# Enviar anexo para email sem a funçao mail e o phpmailer

Tags: php

gostaria de saber se é possivel enviar um anexo em php sem utilizar a função mail e sem utilizar o phpmailer, pois por alguns motivos não tenho a senha nem o login do smtp, não consegui pegar, e a função mail não esta funcionando(fiz a pergunta direitinho sobre o erro mas não teve respostas), dessa maneira gostaria de saber se existiria alguma maneira que eu posso enviar anexo para o e-mail por php.

Obrigado a todos

Comment: Você quer colar a função mail que você fez? Testou localhost ou no servidor? Se não estou enganado a função de mail não funciona localhost.

Comment: A minha pergunta que esta detalhada com o erro e essa:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78796/erro-ao-usar-files-com-fopen-filename-cannot-be-empty

nao quis repetir ela para nao ficar chato aqui, mas ta direto no servidor, e não funciona

Comment: Mas chega a enviar o email?

Comment: Tentou colocar $_FILES['arquivo']['name']; ao inves de tmp_name?

Comment: Ele envia o email mas nao envia o anexo, vou tentar colocar essa aprte andré

Comment: É, ou então ele pode fazer o upload e fazer uma lista de arquivos enviados para o servidor... no corpo do html, ao invés de anexo, já que não conseguiu adaptar o phpmailer

Comment: ele esta enviando, so que o anexo não esta indo

Comment: Tentou buscar um outro exemplo pra ver se funciona? O upload do arquivo foi feito?